# Cómo crear un subdirectorio en un patrón MVC

Tags: php, php7, .htaccess, redirección

Estoy Creando un nuevo proyecto que tiene la siguiente estructura de carpetas y archivos:

[image: Directorios]

Es una estructura que me permite trabajar de forma ordenada y practica. Mis urls quedarian asi:
https://www.mydominio.com/auth/index
donde auth representa el controlador e index representa el metodo principal que esta dentro de ese controlador.

Aqui un ejemplo de mi controlador Auth:

```
class Auth extends Controller
{
public function __construct()
{     
$this->modelUser = $this->model("User");     
}

public function index()
{  
$users = $this->modelUser->GetUsers();
$this->view("pages/users", $users);
}

}
```

a su vez, la clase Controller tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
class Controller
    {

    //load model
    public function model($model)
    {
    //load models
    require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/app/models/'. $model . '.php';
    //instanciar model
    return new $model();
    }

    //load view
    public function view($view, $data = [])
    {
            //check if the view file exists
            if(file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/app/views/'. $view . '.php'))
            {
                require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/app/views/'. $view . '.php';
            }
            else
            {
                die("The file has not found!");
            }
    }


    } //end of class
```

Cuando vamos a cargar una URL, por ejemplo:  https://www.mydominio.com/auth/index lo que sucede es que, se entra primero al archivo .htaccess que esta en la raiz principal del proyecto:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
RewriteRulE (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

esto nos lleva a la carpeta public, especificamente a los archivos index.php y .htaccess que se encuentra allí y tienen el siguiente contenido:

```
//load the app init file
require_once "../app/init.php";

//load the core class
$init = new Core;
```

El archivo .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /public
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

El archivo init.php que se encuentra en la raiz de la carpeta app carga los archivos principales de configuración:

```
    session_start();
    //load Routes and Setups
    require_once "config/config.php";
    //load all the libraries and dependencies
    require_once 'libraries/Controller.php';
    require_once 'libraries/Core.php';
    require_once 'libraries/Database.php';
    require_once 'libraries/SessionControl.php';
```

El archivo .htaccess que se encuentra igualmente en la raiz de la carpeta app contiene:

```
 Options -Indexes
```

Finalmente el archivo más importante dentro de esta estructura es el archivo Core.php, este contiene toda la configuración en cuanto a controladores, modelos y vistas:

```
class Core{
private $actualController = 'auth';
private $actualmethod = 'index';
private $parameter = [];

//Class Construct
public function __construct()
{

$url = $this->getURL(); 
if(isset($url[0]))
{        $direc_name = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/app/controllers/'. ucwords($url[0]) . '.php';
        //check if the controller file exists on the folder
        if(file_exists($direc_name))
        {
        //if it's true
        //save the new active controller  
        $this->actualController = ucwords($url[0]); 
        //clean the content of the array index
        unset($url[0]);
        }
}
else
{
    $this->actualController = "auth";
}


//get the controller
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/app/controllers/' . $this->actualController . '.php');
$this->actualController = new $this->actualController;

//here is the model
if(isset($url[1]))
{
    if(method_exists($this->actualController, $url[1]))
    {
        //the model exist
        $this->actualmethod = $url[1];
        unset($url[1]);
    }
    else
    {
        //the model doesn't exist
        $this->actualmethod = "index";
    }
} 
else
{
    $this->actualmethod = "index";
}


//get parameters
$this->parameter = $url ? array_values($url) : [];

// get callback function
call_user_func_array([$this->actualController, $this->actualmethod], $this->parameter);
} //end of construct

public function getURL()
{
//echo $_GET['url'];

if(isset($_GET['url']))
{
$url = rtrim($_GET['url'], "/");
$url = filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
$url = explode("/", $url);
return $url; 
}

} //end of getURL method

} //end of class
```

Con esta estructura mi proyecto funciona bien, puedo crear un login para mis usuarios y puedo crear las principales vistas que tiene cualquier website (Inicio, Nosotros, Contacto, Articulos, Galleria)

El problema viene cuando quiero crear un pequeño CMS para gestionar el contenido de esas paginas principales y se accederia a este CMS de esta manera: https://www.mydominio.com/admin_panel/main/index donde main seria un controlador e index seria el metodo principal que se encuentra dentro de ese controlador (y es donde se carga la vista).
No se exactamente cómo integrar un subdirectorio para mi CMS en la estructura que ya tengo para mi website.

Comment: ¿Probaste lo mas sencillo? Crear un directorio llamado 'admin_panel' y poner allí el controlador Main.php

Comment: Si necesitas algo más avanzado puedes leer este artículo (en inglés) https://webstudiya.com/user-group-specific-controllers-in-codeigniter/

Comment: @ErikCuaquira pero donde crearía ese directorio? en la raiz del proyecto?

Comment: Creas ese directorio dentro de la carpeta "application/controllers"

Comment: @ErikCuaquira probare, gracias.